# Update Panel in my aspx Page is not working when form.action is used

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I will start from the scratch.

I am converting this page which is an inline code. It submits form values to next page through form.action.

This page have 4 buttons. I only want one button to do form.action.

For that, I tried button's usesubmitbehaviour = "False". That didn't work.
So I tried using update panel. It does work without form.action.

But when I put action = "someurl" in form tag, buttons inside update panel doesn't work.

I am not sure if I explained it well but summary is this, buttons inside doesn't work when I place action property inside form tag or even programmatically.

Note: I want to trigger Form.Action from the single button outside the update panel. And buttons inside update panel should work anything else but Form.Action.

I really appreciate any suggestion and solution.

Comment: please post the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 0):

first have a look [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), make sure you did not misspell the property.

another solution you could try, would be to return false from the button's click handler to prevent it from causing submission:

```
<button onclick="return false">Non-Submitter</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="return Button3_Click()">Non-Submitter Extended</button>
```

```js
function Button3_Click(){
    //...
    //do button 3 stuff here
    //...


    //prevent submission
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

if you have a button inside the update panel, and you need it to cause a full postback, you need to specify it as a PostBack trigger:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

<kbd>**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/8an0zgem/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you sir. But I am certain I spelled it right. I found a solution to it though. Using PostBackUrl property of button instead of Action(I will post solution to help others). However, Update panel not working with action is still a question.

Comment: an update panel is used for partial page rendering. do you need that specific submission button to postback and cause a full page refresh?

Comment: The thing is, I was using Form.action for redirect and submission of form values as it goes to another inline page. As having 4 buttons on same page, I was unable to stop form.action with aspx button. UseSubmitBehaviour = False, doesn't work on Form.action. I used update panel instead to prevent triggering action from remaining three buttons, only to find out that update panel doesn't directly work with Form.Action. Which is quite strange though.

Comment: use the triggers which i added to the answer, and it will work. other way to stop the other buttons from submission (without updatepanel) is simply return false from the client click event: `OnClientClick="return false"`

Comment: I guess I am not clear in my explanation. I want buttons inside update panel to do normal logic. And single button which is outside the panel to perform Form.Action. However, my purpose is solved by using Button's Property. So this question has two points. 1. How to prevent aspx button which run at server to not use submit behavior or prevent them triggering Form.Action. 2. How can update panel and button inside it can work with Form.Action without Triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. Posting it so others don't spend amount of time I did in this.

I am using Button's property PostBackUrl to redirect on button click. This is also submitting form values to posted page.Hence, my purpose to save form values on redirect is solved.

However, Updatepanel still doesn't work with Form.Action. This might be a known issue and needs additional coding to handle that. Not looking into as off now but for sure its something I would look at in future.